# Printing multiple lines simultaneously in C

Tags: c

I was wondering if there was a way to print 2 lines (or more) simultaneously in C.
Something similar to this, but done in 1 loop:

```c
int M(int n){return n+1;}
int F(int n){return n-1;}


int main(void)
{
    int n;
    printf("F(n):\n");
    for (n = 0; n <= 5; n++)
    {
        printf("%d %d ", n, F(n));
    }
    printf("\nM(n):\n");

    for (n = 0; n <= 5; n++)
    {
        printf("%d %d ", n, M(n));
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Edit: the expected output is this:

```
F(n):
0 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5 6
M(n):
0 -1 1 0 2 1 3 2 4 3 5 4
```

But the print would go "column by column".

Comment: You can use the `ncurses` library to move the cursor up and down.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Is high-quality output format ever OS/platform agnostic?

Comment: It is possible to build two strings in the same loop and print them after, but for only two lines it's a lot of trouble. If there are more than two lines consider building a 2-D array in column order before outputting in row order.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I edited the post with the expected output

Comment: Good, but without the definitions of `F` and `M` it's still a bit of a mystery

Comment: Your loops each output 31 pairs of values on a single line.  Your sample output shows 5 pairs of values on each of two lines.  There is no indication of which output pair corresponds to which `printf` call in your code — when you're showing the data from calling `F()` and when you're showing the data from calling `M()`.  We need that information to be able to give you any advice whatsoever.  If you're looking to build up two lines in the loop and then print the resulting lines, say so.  You'll need to know about `snprintf()` and perhaps `asprintf()` if that's available to you.

Comment: Seeing `<=` in a loop with a `0` index start is almost always a bug.

Comment: Short answer is "No". A "line" in C has a line-ending (`'\n'`), so by definition you will write all characters and then a line-ending to your output before you begin writing the next line. Your options are to buffer the complete output (including the line-ending following the 1st line) and write the entire buffer at once, or manipulate the cursor position within the terminal to write at different positions on the screen (using ncurses library or ANSI escape sequences - if supported by your terminal - most all do)

Comment: `M` and `F` are series, I'm trying to print values from `F(0)` to `F(30)` so using `<=` isn't a bug, altough using `< 31` could have been better.
I originaly did not include all 31 values in the expected values edit as I thought it would be understood that it is only the "shape" of the expected output and not the actual output. I understand the confusion and am sorry about it.

Comment: Please read about how to create an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 — or MRE or whatever name SO now uses)
or an
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)
 — the same idea by a different name).  For your original sample output, you could simply have changed 30 to 4 in the code.  It still isn't clear whether the first line of output corresponds to the data from `M()` or `F()`.

Comment: Will do ! Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 3):

There isn't a way in Standard C to repeatedly write some information to one line and some information to another line on the screen, with output alternating between the two lines.

If you can't easily or conveniently generate the information for the first line before generating the information for the second line, then you need to use in-memory storage for the two lines, preparing the data in buffers (strings) in memory and only printing the lines when the information generation is complete.

#### Version 1

This code was hacked together simply and quickly to demonstrate how to prepare two lines in memory.  It contains horribly repetitive code, so it is only adequate as a demonstration.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static inline int M(int x) { return x % 10; }
static inline int F(int x) { return x * x; }

int main(void)
{
    char line1[1024];
    char line2[1024];
    line1[0] = '\0';
    line2[0] = '\0';
    size_t off1 = 0;
    size_t off2 = 0;
    const char *pad = "";

    for (int i = 0; i <= 30; i++)
    {
         int nbytes;
         nbytes = snprintf(line1 + off1, sizeof(line1) - off1,
                              "%s%d %d", pad, i, F(i));
         if (nbytes < 0 || (size_t)nbytes >= sizeof(line2) - off1)
         {
             fprintf(stderr, "formatting failed (%s:%d)\n", __FILE__, __LINE__);
             exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
         }
         off1 += nbytes;
         nbytes = snprintf(line2 + off2, sizeof(line2) - off2,
                              "%s%d %d", pad, i, M(i));
         if (nbytes < 0 || (size_t)nbytes >= sizeof(line2) - off2)
         {
             fprintf(stderr, "formatting failed (%s:%d)\n", __FILE__, __LINE__);
             exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
         }
         off2 += nbytes;
         pad = " ";
    }
    puts(line1);
    puts(line2);

    return 0;
}
```

The basic idea is that you build up the two output lines in the loop (in the arrays — aka buffers — `line1` and `line2`, and only print them when the loop ends.

I'd use cleverer error reporting in my own code — or arrange to dynamically allocate the output lines, etc.  I'd add identifying information to the output lines, and probably separate the pairs of numbers with comma-space rather than just a space (`pad = ", ";`).
Those refinements are unnecessary for giving you the basic answer.

Also, the parallel code structure for two lines cries out for encapsulation into a structure type and a function that can build up the lines — and avoid as much code repetition.

Here is a sequence of programs which use various forms of buffer management, simplifying the main program code.

#### Version 2

This version uses a buffer structure with a fixed-size buffer.  It cannot easily have the buffer size increased without recompiling the program.  This cleans up the main function quite a lot.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static inline int M(int x) { return x % 10; }
static inline int F(int x) { return x * x; }

struct OutputBuffer
{
    size_t   maxlen;
    size_t   offset;
    char     buffer[1024];
};

static void InitBuffer(struct OutputBuffer *output)
{
    output->maxlen = sizeof(output->buffer);
    output->offset = 0;
    output->buffer[0] = '\0';
}

static void AddToLine(struct OutputBuffer *output, const char *pad, int value1, int value2)
{
    char *buffer = output->buffer + output->offset;
    size_t buflen = output->maxlen - output->offset;
    int nbytes = snprintf(buffer, buflen, "%s%d %d", pad, value1, value2);
    if (nbytes < 0 || (size_t)nbytes >= buflen)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "formatting failed (%s:%d) - %d vs %zu\n",
                __FILE__, __LINE__, nbytes, buflen);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    output->offset += nbytes;
}

int main(void)
{
    struct OutputBuffer output1;
    struct OutputBuffer output2;
    InitBuffer(&output1);
    InitBuffer(&output2);
    const char *pad = "";

    for (int i = 0; i <= 30; i++)
    {
         AddToLine(&output1, pad, i, F(i));
         AddToLine(&output2, pad, i, M(i));
         pad = ", ";
    }
    printf("F(n):\n%s\n", output1.buffer);
    printf("M(n):\n%s\n", output2.buffer);

    return 0;
}
```

#### Version 3

This version of the code uses a dynamically allocated buffer, but the program allocates the structure as local variables and calls the initializer routine.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static inline int M(int x) { return x % 10; }
static inline int F(int x) { return x * x; }

struct OutputBuffer
{
    size_t   maxlen;
    size_t   offset;
    char    *buffer;
};

static void OutputBuffer_ctor(struct OutputBuffer *output, size_t buflen) 
{
    output->buffer = malloc(buflen);
    if (output->buffer == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "failed to allocate %zu bytes of memory\n", buflen);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    output->maxlen = buflen;
    output->offset = 0;
    output->buffer[0] = '\0';
}

static void OutputBuffer_dtor(struct OutputBuffer *output) 
{
    if (output != NULL)
    {
        free(output->buffer);
        output->buffer = NULL;
        output->offset = 0;
        output->maxlen = 0;
    }
}

static void AddToLine(struct OutputBuffer *output, const char *pad, int value1, int value2)
{
    char *buffer = output->buffer + output->offset;
    size_t buflen = output->maxlen - output->offset;
    int nbytes = snprintf(buffer, buflen, "%s%d %d", pad, value1, value2);
    if (nbytes < 0 || (size_t)nbytes >= buflen)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "formatting failed (%s:%d) - %d vs %zu\n",
                __FILE__, __LINE__, nbytes, buflen);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    output->offset += nbytes;
}

int main(void)
{
    struct OutputBuffer output1;
    struct OutputBuffer output2;
    OutputBuffer_ctor(&output1, 1024);
    OutputBuffer_ctor(&output2, 1024);
    const char *pad = "";

    for (int i = 0; i <= 30; i++)
    {
         AddToLine(&output1, pad, i, F(i));
         AddToLine(&output2, pad, i, M(i));
         pad = ", ";
    }
    printf("F(n):\n%s\n", output1.buffer);
    printf("M(n):\n%s\n", output2.buffer);

    OutputBuffer_dtor(&output1);
    OutputBuffer_dtor(&output2);

    return 0;
}
```

#### Version 4

This code dynamically allocates the entire structure as well as the buffer within the structure.  It could easily be modified to grow the buffer as required.

This version uses my error reporting routines, the code for which is available in my [SOQ](https://github.com/jleffler/soq) (Stack Overflow Questions) repository on GitHub as files `stderr.c` and `stderr.h` in the [src/libsoq](https://github.com/jleffler/soq/tree/master/src/libsoq) sub-directory.  Usually, I'd pass `argv[0]` to `err_setarg0()`, but the main function is defined as `int main(void)` so I hardwire the name.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "stderr.h"

static inline int M(int x) { return x % 10; }
static inline int F(int x) { return x * x; }

struct OutputBuffer
{
    size_t   maxlen;
    size_t   offset;
    char    *buffer;
};

static struct OutputBuffer *OutputBuffer_ctor(size_t buflen) 
{
    struct OutputBuffer *output = malloc(sizeof(*output));
    if (output == NULL)
        err_syserr("failed to allocate %zu bytes of memory\n", sizeof(*output));
    output->buffer = malloc(buflen);
    if (output->buffer == NULL)
        err_syserr("failed to allocate %zu bytes of memory\n", buflen);
    output->maxlen = buflen;
    output->offset = 0;
    output->buffer[0] = '\0';
    return output;
}

static void OutputBuffer_dtor(struct OutputBuffer *output) 
{
    if (output != NULL)
    {
        free(output->buffer);
        free(output);
    }
}

static void AddToLine(struct OutputBuffer *output, const char *pad, int value1, int value2)
{
    char *buffer = output->buffer + output->offset;
    size_t buflen = output->maxlen - output->offset;
    int nbytes = snprintf(buffer, buflen, "%s%d %d", pad, value1, value2);
    if (nbytes < 0 || (size_t)nbytes >= buflen)
        err_error("formatting operation failed (%s:%d) - %d vs %zu\n",
                  __FILE__, __LINE__, nbytes, buflen);
    output->offset += nbytes;
}

int main(void)
{
    err_setarg0("pl47");
    struct OutputBuffer *output1 = OutputBuffer_ctor(1024);
    struct OutputBuffer *output2 = OutputBuffer_ctor(1024);
    const char *pad = "";

    for (int i = 0; i <= 30; i++)
    {
         AddToLine(output1, pad, i, F(i));
         AddToLine(output2, pad, i, M(i));
         pad = ", ";
    }
    printf("F(n):\n%s\n", output1->buffer);
    printf("M(n):\n%s\n", output2->buffer);

    OutputBuffer_dtor(output1);
    OutputBuffer_dtor(output2);

    return 0;
}
```

#### Further possibilities

The `OutputBuffer` structure type could be separated into a type that's opaque to the main program by declaring the type as an opaque type (probably as `typedef struct OutputBuffer OutputBuffer;`) in a header, along with declarations of the functions to manage variables of the type.  There'd be a separate source file containing the implementation of the functions.

The main program (or any other code using the facility) would use the header and write `OutputBuffer *output = OutputBuffer_ctor(1024);` to define a variable for subsequent use.  There would be a function to add a string to the buffer — `void OutputBuffer_add(OutputBuffer *output, const char *str);` — and a function to access the buffer string — `const char *OutputBuffer_data(OutputBuffer *output)`.

The `AddToLine()` function internals would probably format the extra data into a local buffer and then call `OutputBuffer_add()` to store it — it would be a function using the output buffer package.

Alternatively (or maybe additionally), the package could provide a pair of functions to handle formatting with variable-length argument lists, analogous to `printf()` and `vprintf()`, that could be used to add information to the buffer.

That's overkill (and then some) for this question, though.

#### Summary

Indeed, for the purposes of this question, it seems to me that Version 2 is quite adequate.

Answer (score 0):

Standard C does not support printing on two different lines at the same time, so what the OP is asking is only possible using non-standard methods or buffering of the output which rarely is worth the effort.

I suppose your purpose is to avoid repeating the same code structure more than once.

A different approach could be to place the printing of a series in a function. The OP does not provide definitions of functions `F()` and `M()`, so dummy ones are added for the example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

// Example functions for F and M
int F(int n) {return n+1;}    // Expression for F
int M(int n) {return n-1;}    // Expression for M

// Print the given series (func) from the given start value (n0) to end value (n1)
void printSeries(int n0, int n1, int (* func)(int))
{
   for(int n = n0; n <= n1; n++)
   {
      printf("%d %d ", n, func(n));
   }
   printf("\n");
}

int main()
{
   printSeries(0, 30, F);
   printSeries(0, 30, M);
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can write simple buffered output function. It will print to the virtual screen in memory, then output it when it is ready.

```
typedef struct screen_t
{
    size_t xsize, ysize;
    size_t lastXtouched, lastYtouched;
    int xpos, ypos;
    char *screen;
    int status;
}screen_t;

char *GETYLINE(screen_t *s, size_t line)
{
    return &s -> screen[(s -> xsize + 1) * line];
}

screen_t *xyprintf(screen_t *screen, int xpos, int ypos, const char *format, ...)
{
    va_list va;
    va_start(va, format);

    if(screen && screen -> screen)
    {
        if(xpos == INT_MIN) ypos = screen -> xpos;
        if(ypos == INT_MIN) ypos = screen -> ypos;
        if(xpos >= 0 && xpos < screen -> xsize && ypos >= 0 && ypos < screen -> ysize)
        {
            int chars_printed;
            chars_printed = vsnprintf(GETYLINE(screen, screen -> ysize), screen -> xsize - xpos + 1, format, va);
            memcpy(GETYLINE(screen, ypos) + xpos, GETYLINE(screen, screen -> ysize), chars_printed);
            screen -> xpos = xpos + chars_printed;
        }
    }
    va_end(va);

    return screen;
}

screen_t *initScreen(size_t xsize, size_t ysize)
{
    screen_t *screen = calloc(sizeof(*screen), 1);
    if(screen)
    {
        screen -> screen = malloc((ysize + 1) * (xsize + 1));
        if(screen -> screen)
        {
            screen -> xsize = xsize;
            screen -> ysize = ysize;

            for(size_t y = 0; y < ysize; y++)
            {
                memset(GETYLINE(screen, y), ' ', xsize);
                GETYLINE(screen, y)[xsize] = 0;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            free(screen);
            screen = NULL;
        }
    }
    return screen;
}

void updateScreen(screen_t *screen)
{
    if(screen)
    {
        for(size_t y = 0; y < screen -> ysize; y++)
        {
            puts(GETYLINE(screen, y));
        }
    }
}


int main(void)
{
    screen_t *screen = initScreen(80, 10);
    int c = 0;

    if(screen)
    {
        for(int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
        {
            for(int y = 20; y < 30; y++)
            {
                xyprintf(screen, x * 6, (y - 20), "%d", c++);
            }
        }
        updateScreen(screen);
        free(screen -> screen);
        free(screen);
    }
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/eMdGjnsr8

Answer (score 0):

If you will tolerate 2 loops, you can achieve your goal by nesting them and using an array of function pointers. This is a *very* low maintenance/replication way to extend to more output:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int F(int n) {return n+1;}
int M(int n) {return n-1;}
int Q(int n) {return n+42;}  // spontaneous additional function

int main( void ) {
    struct {
        char *title;
        int (*f)(int);
    } fns[] = {
        { "Q(n):", Q }, // added to this "table"
        { "M(n):", M },
        { "F(n):", F },
    };
    size_t nf = sizeof fns / sizeof fns[0];

    // code below remains unchanged. "data driven"
    while( nf-- ) {
        puts( fns[nf].title ); // used in reverse sequence
        for( int n = 0; n <= 5; n++ )
            printf( "%d %d ", n, fns[nf].f(n) );
        putchar( '\n' );
    }
}
```

Output:

```
F(n):
0 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5 6
M(n):
0 -1 1 0 2 1 3 2 4 3 5 4
Q(n):
0 42 1 43 2 44 3 45 4 46 5 47
```